# Max power from surge protector

Tags: surge-protection, maximum-ratings, outlet

I have a surge-protected outlet from a renowned brand.

On the back it is written 
10A 230v
Up voltage = 0.8KV
Spd class III.

The 8 outlets are Shucko format.

I do not understand that up voltage.
Does it mean that the global load on the 8 outlets must be up to 230x10= 2.300W and a single outlet can bear up to 800W?

Please note, it has also a TV protection for coaxial antenna cable. Maybe that up voltage is related to that secondary protection?

[image]

Comment: Which protector that would be to be specific? Do you have a picture of the text you are talking about?

Comment: Please add a photo to clear ambiguity.

Comment: And since it's a "renowned brand" please give the name and a link to the datasheet for the product.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Up=Voltage Protection Level of a surge arrester](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/259820/up-voltage-protection-level-of-a-surge-arrester)

Comment: Did you mean to write 0.8 kV, instead of “Kw”?

Comment: I did not know that telling brand names is allowed, it is a belkin surgemaster F9M823it2M. It is a product sold 11 years ago, so I cannot find a datasheet.

The exact text on the back is 

Non-Rewirable portable socket outlet

10A 230V (Ac symbol) 50&60Hz

up voltage = 0,8KV

SPD Class III
IP20

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Up should be written U<sub>p</sub> where *U* is the voltage rating and *p* is for "protection" or similar.

*U* is used to indicate voltage measurement most commonly in Germany. The intent is to avoid confusion with the "V" symbol and is more consistent with our use of *I* for current (amperes / A) and *R* or *Z* for resistance or impedance in ohms (Ω).

The protection rating only tells you the voltage at which it will clamp. It doesn't tell you how much power it can handle.

Note that 0.8KV would read as 0.8 kelvin-volts. It should have been written "0.8 kV". Capitals matter!

Comment: I added a picture, as you can see up is written "plain" and KV is really KV

Comment: And "up" is in lowercase. I think we're into techno-babble territory.